# How to redirect root to subdirectory using .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am currently using shared hosting and have no way to put my files outside the "public_html" folder.

To work around this, I want to rewrite my "root" site to a subdirectory using the script below in an .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1
```

Which works great, except when I navigate to *www.example.com/subdir/*. That url does not redirect to anywhere, it simply displays the subdirectory. This is a problem for relative urls and such.

Is there a way to continue rewriting my root to a subdirectory while also rewriting *www.example.com/subdir/* to *www.example.com*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdir/$1 [L]
```

And use this rule in `/subdir/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdir/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /subdir/(\S*)\s
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: From what I have been testing, you can also use that in the root .htaccess. The key is THE_REQUEST

Comment: Yes that is true, it can be done in root .htaccess as long as `/subdir/.htaccess` doesn't exist.